# Rails 6 access helper method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

An application must communicate to an API a link.  Thus the controller tries to define a variable as follows:

```
link = helper.link_to(I18n.t 'cart.check_cart_status', acqs_url)
```

However in the console this returns

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `acqs_url' for main:Object)
```

when this methods [respects the definition in the API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Access to the helpers in controllers has changed quite a bit from version to version.
What is wrong with the above syntax in Rails 6.1.3 ? or is the call to I18n gumming things up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing parantheses around the `I18n.t` argument - it should be `link_to(I18n.t('cart.check_cart_status'), acqs_url)`, otherwise the URL will be passed as an argument to `I18.t` method, not to the `link_to` method.

Also, if you're trying to test the assignment in the rails console, you should call it like this:

```
helper.link_to(I18n.t('cart.check_cart_status'), app.acqs_url)
```

Comment: That hit the nail on its head.  Just a comment here: this was not possible to piece together via the api and rails guides references. *oddly I had that syntax* but without the `app.` for the 'url'.  If I read correctly, the assignment in console take that prefix, in the controller, not, yes?

Comment: Correct - in the controller you don't need the `app.` prefix